# angular 4 redirects to not found page for any route

Tags: angular

Hi i have this routes in my app:

```
const routes : Routes = [
  {path : '', redirectTo: '/login',pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'system', loadChildren: './system/system.module#SystemModule'},
  {path:'**',component:NotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
    preloadingStrategy:PreloadAllModules
  })],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
```

but when i run the app it routes to not found page component.

if i try this on system routes:

```
const routes : Routes = [
  {path:'',component:SystemComponent,canActivateChild:[AuthGuard],children:[
      {path:'bill',component:BillPageComponent},
      {path:'records',component:RecordsPageComponent},
      {path:'planning',component:PlanningPageComponent},
      {path:'history',component:HistoryPageComponent},
      {path:'history/:id',component:HistoryDetailsComponent}
    ]},
  {path:'**',component:NotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports:[
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

it works ok but on top level routes it does not.
please advise.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
 {path : '', redirectTo: '/login',pathMatch: 'full'}
```

for default route. however,  `login` route is not defined. that is why your application is redirected to NotFound page

Answer (score 0):

Please add `/login` in you route also. Because it's not able to find login route.

```
const routes : Routes = [
  {path : '', redirectTo: '/login',pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
  {path: 'system', loadChildren: './system/system.module#SystemModule'},
  {path:'**',component:NotFoundComponent}
];
```

Comment: Hi guys, thank you very much for advice.  the login & register routes defined in auth module the routes as follows: `const routes: Routes = [
  {path : '', component: AuthComponent, children: [
      {path : 'login',component: LoginComponent},
      {path : 'register',component: RegisterComponent}
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 
  exports: [RouterModule]
})`

Comment: Fixed you issue ?

Comment: What is the issue now ?

Comment: solvedthe problem this those routes: `const routes : Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'/login',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path : '',component:AuthComponent,children:[
      {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
      {path:'register',component:RegisterComponent}
    ]},
  {path: 'system', loadChildren: './system/system.module#SystemModule'},
  {path:'**',component:NotFoundComponent}
];` but if i want the auth routes on separate module still does not work.